# Implementing LEFT JOIN explicitly in Django

Tags: django, left-join

I have been thru ***endless*** posts on Django and the LEFT JOIN problem and but have not found anyone that has a solution in the 2.2 version of Django. Whilst in years past it seems there were ways to get around this problem, the Django team seem to have shut down every mechanism people have employed to achieve the most simple but necessary query - the LEFT JOIN.
Here is a simle ***example*** of what I am trying to do (it is a simple example to reflect a real world scenario so please do not offer ways to redesign the models... all I want is the age old LEFT JOIN in SQL .... that simple):

```
from django.db import models
from uuid import uuid4
class People(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, editable=False, default=uuid4)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Book(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, editable=False, default=uuid4)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    author = models.ForeignKey(People)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(People, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
```

How would I achive an output showing all books **and** the publisher *if there is a publisher* (otherwise just blank)

```
Books.objects.filter(Q(publisher__isnull=True | Q(publisher__isnull=False)
```

... produces an INNER JOIN which will obviously only show books that have a publisher assigned. 
The query I am looking for would be of the form:
    select * from book LEFT JOIN people ON book.publisher_id=people.id

... or do I have to resort to raw SQL for this most simple of requirements?

Answer (score 1):

You can perform a [**`.select_related(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) here:

```
Book.objects.select_related('publisher')
```

This will fetch both the `Book` data and the related `Publisher` if it exists. So `some_book.publisher` where `some_book` originates from this queryset, will not result in an extra query to fetch the publisher. The query this will look like:

```
SELECT book.id, book.name, book.author_id, book.publisher_id,
       people.id, people.name
FROM book
LEFT OUTER JOIN people ON book.publisher_id = people.id
```

Comment: I have seen that select_related performs inner join, but here it is left outer join. It is because of `null=True` in ForeignKey or am I missing something?

Comment: @NalinDobhal: well it usually performs a LEFT OUTER JOIN. But for non-nullable fields, it can be optimized to an INNER JOIN :). I think it is thus strictly speaking the other way around. But it boils down to the same :) You can check it with `print(Book.objects.select_related('publisher').query)`, which indeed yields a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: Well I should have actually run my simplified model and tested before posting it ... in my "real life" model that has a foreign key to another model exactly as depicted in the relations above, that same select_related() method still produces an INNER JOIN ... will try to figure out what is causing Django to decide NOT to use a LEFT JOIN for my case

Comment: @ChristopherBroderick: usually that is because the Django ORM found a something why it is not necessary to use a LEFT JOIN. It is thus an "optimization" to transform LEFT JOINs to INNER JOINs. Either that is a valid reason, or a bug.

Comment: My own stupidity ... the ForeignKey field was required not optional and therefore a LEFT JOIN is inefficient and unnecessary